# Reverse Command Line Parameters in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have to write a simple bash script for my programming class. The idea is to use a for loop with `$*` (names of Files as Command Line Parameters). The task is to reverse and print out the Command Line parameters while still using the `for inFile in $*; do` loop.

I have no idea how to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash

for inFile in $*;do
  echo $inFile
done
```

I know this doesn't work it just prints out the command line parameters in order.

Comment: I guess this isn't related to c but the course is C programming so......

Comment: Prefer `#!/bin/sh` for POSIX compatability (Linux, Unix, BSD, Solaris, Mac OS X, ...) rather than Linux "lock-up"

Comment: What's the full question? Do you have to sort the results in the script?

Comment: @pmg bash is not "linux-only", and the question is about bash, there is no point in limiting yourself with POSIX-only features.

Answer (score 0):

The idea to loop over `$*` to reverse command line arguments is broken,
when any command line argument contains a white space. For example when the command line arguments are `foo` and `"bar baz"`, the output of the script in the question will be:

> ```
> foo
> bar
> baz
> ```

When the correct output should be:

> ```
> foo
> bar baz
> ```

The exact wording of the task is important.

For example, if the task is to print the arguments in reverse, and it doesn't mention `$*`, then you can use a counting loop in reverse, and `${!i}` to expand to the value of the numbered positional parameters:

```
# nice clean solution
for ((i = $#; i > 0; i--)); do
    echo "${!i}"
done
```

Another example, if the task insists that you must use `$*` and accepts that the command line arguments will only have supported characters, then you could collect the parameters into an array, and then print the content of the array in reverse, again with a counting loop:

```
args=()
# not recommended, unsafe due to shell expansion of $*
for arg in $*; do
    args+=("$arg")
done

for ((i = ${#args[@]} - 1; i >= 0; i--)); do
    echo "${args[i]}"
done
```

If you are not allowed to use arrays, then you can prepend values to a string, and then iterate over that string:

```
# dirtiest solution, with unsafe expansions and unquoted variables, not recommended
args=
for arg in $*; do
    args="$arg $args"
done

for arg in $args; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```